# Querying data based from id (primary key) on many to many eloquent pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I make a many to many relationship between two tables, with id (primary key) on the pivot table while the pivot table is related to another table.

Here's an 
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZKYS.jpg)

---

```
|Table Product        |
|- id                 |
|- name               |
|- price              |
-----------------------
|Table Warehouse      |
|- id                 |
|- location           |
|- staff_id           |
-----------------------
|Table Stock (Pivot)  |
|- id                 |
|- product_id         |
|- warehouse_id       |
-----------------------
|Table Stock Movement |
|- id                 |
|- stock_id           |
|- quantity           |
|- description        |
-----------------------
```

The model class

```
// Warehouse model
class Warehouse extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'stocks')->using('App\Stock');
    }
}

// Product model
class Product extends Model
{
    public function warehouses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Warehouse', 'stocks')->using('App\Stock');
    }
}

// Stock model, this is the pivot table.
// Note that it's not extends to laravel eloquent model anymore
class Stock extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'stocks';

    public function stock_movement()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StockMovement');
    }
}

// StockMovement model
class StockMovement extends Model
{
    public function stock()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Stock');
    }
}
```

if i retrieve the pivot table from product model, **i can't get the pivot table id. i want to use it to retrieve the stock model**

eloquent query :

```
$warehouses = Product::find($product_id)->warehouses;
return $warehouses;
```

JSON Response :

```
{
    id: 1,
    staff_id: 1,
    created_at: "2018-07-02 13:40:20",
    updated_at: "2018-07-02 13:40:20",
    pivot: {
        product_id: 1,
        warehouse_id: 1
    }
}
```

how to get the pivot table id?

do i have to **change the eloquent query?**,

or **change the relationship between tables?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access extra filed in pivot using `withPivot` like this

```
class Stock extends Pivot
{
    protected $table = 'stocks';

    public function stock_movement()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\StockMovement')->withPivot('id');
    }
}
```

Now you can access it

```
$warehouses = Product::find($product_id)->warehouses;

foreach($warehouses as $warehouse){
    dd($warehouse->pivot->id);
}
```

**Note:** It is not good practice to define relationship in pivot table, because then you can't load that relationship with eager loading. If your pivot table has relation with third table then better user `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relationship.